# What does it mean for the jacobian matrix to be triangular?

Tags: jacobian

I found a research paper that talks about of the orthogonality or the semi orthogonality of the jacobian matrix of a function, that got me wondering about the properties of what if the jacobian matrix is a orthogonal, and what would happen if is only triangular ?

Comment: If $f$ is your function from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, then you can write its component functions $f = (f_1,...,f_n)$. If $J(f)$ is triangular then it means $f_i$ is a function which only depends on the first $i$ variables $x_1,...,x_i$.